# Is there a shiny textInput widget with a "reset" button incorporated?

Tags: r, shiny, widget, reset, textinput

I developed an online shiny application which contains a `textInput()` widget to input a location name and, accordingly, redirect the user on that location on a map (exploiting the Google API's features through the `geocode` package).

I would like to change my current `textInput()` widget with another one that has a "X" button incorporated in it to automatically delete the text that the user inserts. Please check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21DEH.png) to see an example of it (the "X" button is marked in red).

Do you know if it's possible to do inside a shiny app? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)

clearableTextInput <- function(inputId, label, value = ""){
  el <- tags$div(
    tags$label(label, `for` = inputId),
    tags$span(
      class = "text-input-clearable",
      tags$input(id = inputId, type = "text", value = value),
      tags$span(title = "Clear", HTML("&times;"))
    )
  )
  js <- sprintf('
  var textInput = document.getElementById("%s");
  var clearBtn = textInput.nextElementSibling;
  textInput.onkeyup = function() {
    clearBtn.style.visibility = (this.value.length) ? "visible" : "hidden";
  };
  clearBtn.onclick = function() {
    this.style.visibility = "hidden";
    textInput.value = "";
    Shiny.setInputValue("%s", "");
  };
  ', inputId, inputId)
  tagList(el, singleton(tags$script(HTML(js))))
}

CSS <- "
.text-input-clearable {
  border:1px solid;
  padding:1px 6px 1px 1px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.text-input-clearable input {
  border:none;
  background:none;
  outline:none;
  padding:0 0;
  margin:0 0;
  font:inherit;
}
.text-input-clearable span {
  cursor:pointer;
  color:blue;
  font-weight:bold;
  visibility:hidden;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(CSS))
  ),
  br(),
  clearableTextInput("txt", "Label"),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["txt"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["txt"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Really nice and elegant solution Stéphane. Thanks as always.