# Clear text selection in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

i'm new to Shiny and JS is non existent. Looking at this great forum i've built an app that allows users to select data. I however tried to add a 'reset button' so that users can clear their selection to start again but it's not working? i'm not sure how to do this?

```
library(shiny)

text1 <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec quam ut tortor interdum pulvinar id vitae magna. Curabitur commodo consequat arcu et lacinia. Proin at diam vitae lectus dignissim auctor nec dictum lectus. Fusce venenatis eros congue velit feugiat, ac aliquam ipsum gravida. Cras bibendum malesuada est in tempus. Suspendisse tincidunt, nisi non finibus consequat, ex nisl condimentum orci, et dignissim neque est vitae nulla." 
text2 <- "Aliquam ut purus neque. Maecenas justo orci, semper eget purus eu, aliquet molestie mi. Duis convallis ut erat at faucibus. Quisque malesuada ante elementum, tempor felis et, faucibus orci. Praesent iaculis nisi lorem, non faucibus neque suscipit eu. Ut porttitor risus eu convallis tristique. Integer ac mauris a ex maximus consequat eget non felis. Pellentesque quis sem aliquet, feugiat ligula vel, convallis sapien. Ut suscipit nulla leo"
highlight <- '
                function getSelectionText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection) {
text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return text;
}

document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
var selection = getSelectionText();
Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", selection);
};
'

coded_text <- character(0)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$script(highlight),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           tags$h1("Text to code"),
           tags$h2("From table"),
           tableOutput("table"),
           tags$h2("From raw text"),
           verbatimTextOutput("text"),
           actionButton("vClear", "Clear Selection")
    ),
    column(4,
           tags$h1("Coding options"),
           actionButton("code1", "Assign selected text to Code1"),
           tags$h1("Code1 output"),
           verbatimTextOutput("selected_text")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame(paragraph = 1:2, text = c(text1, text2))
  })

  output$text <- renderText(paste(text1, text2))

  coded <- eventReactive(input$code1, {
    coded_text <<- c(coded_text, input$mydata)
    coded_text
  })

  output$selected_text <- renderPrint({
    coded()
  })
  
   observeEvent(input$vClear, {
   coded <- NULL
    coded_text <- NULL
   }) # I tried this but nothing happens!
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Everytime a user clicks on 'Clear Selection' button i'm hoping for the selected text to be reset.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can use my solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60543589/1100107), or use the widget `clearableTextInput` in the package **spsComps**. Instead of clearing by pressing a button, with these solutions you can clean by clicking a small cross in the text input.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent as far as I understood this is about clearing a selection in constant text - not clearing the text itself.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can implement an `onclick` event for the reset button calling `removeAllRanges()`. Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)

text1 <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec quam ut tortor interdum pulvinar id vitae magna. Curabitur commodo consequat arcu et lacinia. Proin at diam vitae lectus dignissim auctor nec dictum lectus. Fusce venenatis eros congue velit feugiat, ac aliquam ipsum gravida. Cras bibendum malesuada est in tempus. Suspendisse tincidunt, nisi non finibus consequat, ex nisl condimentum orci, et dignissim neque est vitae nulla." 
text2 <- "Aliquam ut purus neque. Maecenas justo orci, semper eget purus eu, aliquet molestie mi. Duis convallis ut erat at faucibus. Quisque malesuada ante elementum, tempor felis et, faucibus orci. Praesent iaculis nisi lorem, non faucibus neque suscipit eu. Ut porttitor risus eu convallis tristique. Integer ac mauris a ex maximus consequat eget non felis. Pellentesque quis sem aliquet, feugiat ligula vel, convallis sapien. Ut suscipit nulla leo"
highlight <- '
                function getSelectionText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection) {
text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return text;
}

document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
var selection = getSelectionText();
Shiny.setInputValue("mydata", selection);
};
'
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$script(HTML(highlight)),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           tags$h1("Text to code"),
           tags$h2("From table"),
           tableOutput("table"),
           tags$h2("From raw text"),
           verbatimTextOutput("text"),
           actionButton("vClear", "Clear Selection", onclick = 'const reset = function(){Shiny.setInputValue("mydata", ""); window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();}; reset();')
    ),
    column(4,
           tags$h1("Coding options"),
           actionButton("code1", "Assign selected text to Code1"),
           tags$h1("Code1 output"),
           verbatimTextOutput("selected_text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  coded_text <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$code1, {
    coded_text(c(coded_text(), input$mydata))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$vClear, {
    coded_text(NULL)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame(paragraph = 1:2, text = c(text1, text2))
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText(paste(text1, text2))
  
  output$selected_text <- renderPrint({
    coded_text()
  }) # |> bindEvent(input$code1)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]

PS: in [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) you should try to avoid global variables and use `reactiveVal` or `reactiveValues` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help, do you know how i can also clear verbatimTextOutput("selected_text")?

Comment: @tezzaaa please see my edit.

Comment: thank you for this, it clears out the text but i'm then unable to select other text after that?

Comment: @tezzaaa that's not the case here - it's working fine after a reset (please see the added gif). Please try again with a fresh R session.

Comment: ah yes sorry i clicked on the wrong tab! thank you so much, have a great weekend, I'm so grateful